# Confusion in notation of functions.

Tags: functions, notation

Let us consider the following notations for $x \in X,y\in Y ,z \in Z$.

$$F(x,y,z)=x^yy^z$$

$$F_x(y,z)=x^yy^z$$

I am clear with former notation , but I saw latter one too , what's the difference between them ?

Is there any valid difference ?

If no difference then why multiple notations ?

Comment: There is no real difference. It is just a matter of emphasis. With $F_x(y,z)$ you are visually emphasizing the $y$ and $z$.

Comment: @DanChristensen No it is not "just a matter of emphasis", the objects one is referring to are different.

Comment: @did Do we not have $\forall x\in X: \forall y\in Y: \forall z\in Z: F(x,y,z)=F_x(y,z)$?

Comment: @DanChristensen We do. And?

Comment: @Did So, they are just two different representations of the same thing.

Comment: @DanChristensen No, $F$ and $F_x$ are not "just two different representations of the same thing".

Comment: @Did  I disagree.

Comment: @DanChristensen Care to explain why? Or are you above argumentation?

Comment: @Did I have already explained why they are the same. Why do you think they must be different?

Comment: @DanChristensen You explained nothing. The functions $F$ and $F_x$ are defined on two different sets hence they cannot be "the same thing".

Comment: @did They are both the same subsets of $X\times Y\times Z$.

Comment: @DanChristensen No. The graph of $F$ is a subset of $(X\times Y\times Z)\times W$ while the graph of each $F_x$ is a subset of $(Y\times Z)\times W$ hence they do not coincide (and none of them is a subset of $X\times Y$). Please *think* before posting. Anyway this thread is already too long so I am out.

Comment: @did Correction: They are the same subset of $X\times Y\times Z\times W$ where $W$ is the codomain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$F$ is a function of three variables ($x, y, z$). Whereas $F_{x}$ consists of two variables ($y, z$) and $x$ is fixed.

Comment: So $x$ can't vary ?

Comment: Is it true that $F_x \subseteq F$ ?

Comment: Yes it can but produces two different functions, suppose $x_{1}, x_{2} \in X$ then $F_ {x_{1}}$ and $F_ {x_{2}}$ are the functions produced. Yes, $F_ {x} \subset F$ holds

Comment: I'm not sure how to make any sense of the assertion that $F_x \subset F$.

Comment: @Richard What do you mean when you confirm that $F_x\subset F$? hanu: Why do you ask whether $F_x\subseteq F$?

Comment: I meant the codomain of the functions

Comment: Since when the codomain of a function is identified to the function?

Comment: @Hurkyl Since any function is a set and $F_x$ is function at a particular $x$ , so i represented as subset . Did

Comment: @hanu (Please signal comments to me when you cite my username, thanks.) OK, any function is a set (its graph, actually, but no big deal) but then $F\subseteq X\times Y\times Z\times W$ while $F_x\subseteq Y\times Z\times W$ for each $x$ in $X$ hence $F_x\subseteq F$ seems impossible, no?

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to write the evaluation of a univariate function:

- $f(x)$ is the function $f$ evaluated at $x$
- $fx$ is the function $f$ evaluated at $x$. Or occasionally the function $x$ evaluated at $f$
- $a_n$ is the function $a$ evaluated at $n$. Usually $n$ is drawn from some interval of integers and we call $a$ a "sequence" rather than a "function"
- $a^n$ is the function $a$ evaluated at $n$. We don't usually use superscripts this way, but in some contexts it's very useful.
- ${}_na$ is the function $a$ evaluated at $n$. Again this is unusual but occasionally convenient (usually because we are using notation where the other places around $a$ already have something, so we can't use that spot for notating evaluation)

There are surely others that get used, but this is all I could think of off hand.

Parsing your second example, $F_x$ is the function $F$ evaluated at $x$. But the values of $F$ are *functions* rather than, say, numbers. Thus $F_x(y,z)$ is the evaluation of the function $F_x$ at $(y,z)$.

Note that $F(x,y,z)$ and $F_x(y,z)$ can't make sense in the same context; the usage of $F$ in the two cases is for two different types of things. (although on some occasions there is utility in using the same letter to mean different things, it usually leads to confusion)

Comment: "$F_x$ is the function $F$ evaluated at $x$" Hmmm... no. The function $F$ can be evaluated at some $(x,y,z)$ in $X\times Y\times Z$ (yielding $F(x,y,z)$), not at some $x$ in $X$. There is a function, which can be evaluated at $x$ giving $F_x$ but it is not $F$.

Comment: @Did: His first example is defining an element $F \in (X \times Y \times Z)^W$. His second example is defining an element $F \in X^{(Y \times Z)^W}$. They are not the same $F$. (although they are closely related)

Comment: You probably mean $F\in W^{X\times Y\times Z}$ in the first formulation and $F\in (W^{Y\times Z})^X$ in the second formulation, but thanks, I now understand why you said that $F_x$ is $F$ evaluated at $x$ in the second formulation.